# Obtain the URI of a Controller method call

Tags: scala, playframework, routes, uri

I'm writing a Play 2.3.2 application in Scala.

In my application I'm writing a method that call an other controller method like the following:

```
def addTagToUser = CorsAction.async { request =>
     implicit val userRestFormat = UserFormatters.restFormatter
     implicit val inputFormat = InputFormatters.restFormatter
     implicit val outputWriter = OutputFormatters.restWriter
     //update the tag of a user
     def updateTagToUserDB(value: JsValue): Future[Boolean] = {
       val holder : WSRequestHolder = WS.url("http://localhost:9000/recommendation/ advise")
       val complexHolder = holder.withHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/json")
       complexHolder.post(value).map(response => response.status match {//handle the response
         case 200 => true
         case _ => false
       }
         )       
     }
     val jsonData = request.body.asJson //get the json data
     jsonData match {
       case Some(x) => x.validate[Input] match {
         case JsSuccess(input, _) => updateTagToUserDB(x).flatMap(status => status match {
           case true => Future{Ok}
           case _ => Future{InternalServerError("Error on update the users tags")}
         })
         case e: JsError => Future{BadRequest("json bad formed")}
       }

       case None => Future{BadRequest("need a json value")}

     }
```

}

But in this code I've the problem that the url is create static, Is possible to get the absolute uri of a Controller method in Play??

How can I make that??

Comment: I want to obtain the uri of another controller method..
For example I had the controller Application with the advise method and I want to find the Application.advise absolute uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [reverse routing](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaRouting#Reverse-routing) section of Play docs, you can achieve this with the following method call:

```
routes.Application.advise()
```

Note that `routes` exists in `controllers` so if you are in `controllers` package you can simply access reverse routes with `routes.ControllerName.methodName`.

From other parts of the code you need to use the fully qualified package, i.e. `controllers.reverse.Application.advise()`.

If controller method takes a parameter you need to pass the desired argument and get the actual route, for example `routes.Application.someMethod(10)`.

Reverse routing is a powerful asset in Play toolbox which frees you from repeating yourself. It's future proof in a sense that if you change your route, the change will be reflected automatically to the whole application.

### Alternative

This approach may not be the best approach.

Redirecting to another controller makes sense, but sending a request to another controller which resides just inside the same web app is overkill and unnecessary. It would be more wise if your web app serves responses to outside not to request a response from itself.

You can easily avoid it by putting the common logic somewhere else and use it from both controllers. According to best practices a good controller is a thin one! By better layering life will be much easier.